# header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')

Tags: php

This coding is giving me crums.  I want to display ALL the Images from the Database  PHP  Please Help

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "test") or die('Could not connect to server');
mysql_select_db("myweb", $con) or die('Could not connect to database');

$query = "SELECT * FROM photos";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$pic = $row['pic'];

echo $pic;
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't even try to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll need a while and img tags.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

    $pic = $row['pic'];

?>

<img src="<?= $pic ?>"></img>

<?php } ?>
```

Something like that.

In this answer I'm considering that the database contains only the url of the images.

Your page's Content-Type shouldn't be image/jpeg if you're going to use HTML on it.

Also, quit using `mysql_*`, start using `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.